# unable to run Jupyter notebook after Pip3 install

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Getting error msg in terminal

```
Jupyter: command not found
```

after pip3 install.
I did some reading and it seems to have to do with the path pip installed in being different to my working directory? 
The jupyter is installed in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages` 
and my default path seems to be

```
export   echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

I tried to move my path to where jupyter is installed by running `:PATH="$HOME/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bin:$PATH"`
But it still didn't work

Comment: Have you tried using a virtual environment? Generally these types of problems go away once you do;  https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using Linux (based on echo $PATH), you should be able to get working with the following: [venv docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)

1: Verify python3.7

```
which python3.7
/usr/local/bin/python3.7
```

2: Install venv (look up how for your distribution)

3: Navigate to your project

```
(mkdir JupyterTest)
cd JupyterTest
```

4: Create a virtual environment

```
python3.7 -m venv venv
```

5: Activate the virtual environment

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

6: Ensure it took

```
python --version #(Should output python 3.7.x)
Python 3.7.0
```

7: install jupyter

```
pip install jupyter
```

8: Run a notebook

```
jupyter-notebook
```

I've tested the above on my Linux Mint machine, and I have several versions of Python installed in parallel.

Comment: Thanks but i got error Permission denied: '/path' when trying to install venv

Comment: I'd really recommend that you work through the venv install issue (I assume you used 'sudo'?) and do it the way prescribe above. If you don't use virtual environments, this is unlikely to be the last error of this kind that you will have.

Answer (score 0):

this one liner worked for me:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/bin
```